# How to change boolean values datatable to understandable values in asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatable

I've used `datatable` for showing my data.I want to change boolean values to understandable values for example, in my project I have two columns Gender and IsActive I want to change Gender with values Male and Female and also IsActive column.

[image]

```
@model  IEnumerable<Dentistry.Areas.ViewModels.UserViewModel>


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "مدیریت کاربران";

}

@*<h2>مدیریت کاربران</h2>*@

@section Styles{

    <link href="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/datatables/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/datatables/plugins/bootstrap/datatables.bootstrap-rtl.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-modal/css/bootstrap-modal-bs3patch.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-modal/css/bootstrap-modal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
}

<style>
    .table-checkable tr > td:first-child, .table-checkable tr > th:first-child {
        text-align: center;
        max-width: 50000px;
        min-width: 40px;
        padding-right: 0;
        padding-left: 0;
    }
    #delete .modal-header {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #EFEFEF;
        background: #e7505a !important;
    }
    .modal {
        border-radius: 0px;
        -webkit-border-radius : 0px;
        -moz-border-radius: 0px;
    }
</style>


<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <!-- BEGIN EXAMPLE TABLE PORTLET-->
    <div class="portlet box green">
        <div class="portlet-title">
            <div class="caption">
                <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i>کاربران
            </div>
            <div class="actions">
                <a href="/Admin/Users/Create" data-target="#create" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> کاربر جدید
                </a>
                <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                    <i class="fa fa-print"></i> چاپ
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="portlet-body">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-checkable order-column myDatatable" id="myDatatable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        @*<th class="table-checkbox">
                                <label class="mt-checkbox mt-checkbox-single mt-checkbox-outline">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="group-checkable" data-set="myDatatable .checkboxes" />
                                    <span></span>
                                </label>
                            </th>*@
                        <th>نام کاربری </th>
                        <th>نام </th>
                        <th>نام خانوادگی</th>
                        <th>جنسیت</th>
                        <th>ایمیل</th>
                        <th>وضعیت</th>
                        <th>شماره تماس</th>
                        <th>آدرس</th>
                        <th>ویرایش</th>
                        <th>حذف</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>


            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<div id="edit" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" data-width="760">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
        <h3 class="modal-title">ویرایش کاربران</h3>
    </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">

        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div id="delete" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" data-width="760">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
        <h3 class="modal-title">آیا قصد حذف این کاربر را دارید؟</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">

        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div id="create" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" data-width="760">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-user-plus"></i>   کاربر جدید </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">


    </div>

</div>

    <!-- BEGIN Portlet PORTLET-->

    <!-- END Portlet PORTLET-->




@section scripts{


    <!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL PLUGINS -->
    <script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/scripts/datatable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/datatables/datatables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/datatables/plugins/bootstrap/datatables.bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/pages/scripts/table-datatables-managed.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- END PAGE LEVEL SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-modal/js/bootstrap-modalmanager.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-modal/js/bootstrap-modal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- BEGIN PAGE LEVEL SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="~/Areas/admin/assets/pages/scripts/ui-extended-modals.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {

            var oTable = $('#myDatatable').DataTable({
                "ajax": "/Users/GetUsers",
                "language": {
                    "search": "جستجو:",
                    "lengthMenu": " تعداد _MENU_ رکورد در هر صفحه"
                },
                "autoWidth": true,
                "columns": [

                    { "data": "UserName", },
                    { "data": "FirstName", },
                    { "data": "LastName", },
                    { "data": "Gender", },
                    { "data": "Email", },
                    { "data": "IsActive", },
                    { "data": "PhoneNumber", },
                    { "data": "Address", },

                    {
                        "data": "UserId", "width": "50px", "render": function (data) {
                            //
                            return '<a class="btn btn-info fa fa-pencil" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#edit"  href="/Admin/Users/Edit/' + data + '"></a>';
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "UserId", "width": "50px", "render": function (data) {
                            return '<a class="btn btn-danger fa fa-trash" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal" data-target="#delete" href="/Admin/Users/Delete/' + data + '"></a>';
                        }
                    }
                ]

            });

            $('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {

                $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
            });

        });


    </script>
}
```

Comment: check my answer. You can do without adding new property through data table columndef option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set value in columndef for gender and isactive columns. Here is sample for isactive column. Add same for gender column under columndef array.

```
    "columnDefs": [
        {
                            "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                return data?'Yes':'No';
            },
           "targets": 0 // replace 0 by your column if
         }
     ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add properties to your model.
Something like this:

```
    public string isActiveString
    {
        // Note that this is inverted!
        get { return IsActive ? "Yes" : "No"; }
    }

    public string GenderString
    {
        // Note that this is inverted!
        get { return Gender ? "Male" : "Female"; }
    }
```